# Karp Rabin Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, rabin-karp

I am implementing karp-rabin substring matching algorithm. My implementation works fine when I call hash_string() method on substrings but fails when I implement rolling hash. My rolling hash value keeps growing, and I can't figure out why.

```
def hash_string(string, base):
    power = len(string) - 1
    hash_value = 0
    for i in range(power, -1, -1):
        hash_value += (ord(string[i]) * (base ** power))
    return hash_value

def karp_rabin(string, substring):
    substrhash = hash_string(substring, 256)
    rolling_hash_val = hash_string(string[0:len(substring)], 256)
    for i in range(len(string) - len(substring) + 1):
        if substrhash == rolling_hash_val and string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
            return i
        if i < len(string) - len(substring):
            print rolling_hash_val
            print (ord(string[i]) * (256 ** (len(substring) - 1))) * 256
            rolling_hash_val = (rolling_hash_val - (ord(string[i]) * (256 ** (len(substring) - 1)))) * 256 + ord(string[i + len(substring)])

print karp_rabin('ababababaababab', 'aab')
```

More specifically, the problem arises here:

```
rolling_hash_val = (rolling_hash_val - (ord(string[i]) * (256 ** (len(substring) - 1)))) * 256 + ord(string[i + len(substring)])
```

The rolling hash value increases by orders of magnitude, even though the substring length remains the same. Is this rolling hash implementation correct?

Comment: *"fails"* is **not** a useful description of the problem. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have explained it already. "My rolling hash value keeps growing, and I can't figure out why."

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example with more detail, per the Help Center article I just linked to? An outline of the debugging you've done so far would be useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling hashes are normally done in modulo arithmetic. I mean, there's all sorts of addition and multiplication and exponentiation going on there -- if it's not modulo `n` (for some `n`), yes, things are going to grow.

(Incidentally, don't be tempted to just do the hash update followed by the modulus. With normal-sized integers, that's not a good idea. Use actual modular exponentiation.)